# Execute anonymous function on load, then execute again every 30 seconds using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

Sorry if this has already been answered, I am just learning Javascript and can't seem to figure this one out.

I have the anonymous function below, which reads a json file and updates the html. It successfully updates every 30 s, the problem is I have to wait 30 s for the data to appear when the page loads. How can I modify the code below so it updates on load, and then it updates every 30 s?

```
$(function () {
  setTimeout(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });  
  $.getJSON("data/ticket_data.json", function(result){
  /*some more stuff here*/
  });
},30000);
});
```

Comment: Make it a named function.  Call the named function yourself, then pass the named function to `setInterval()`.

Comment: You may also be interested in `setIntervalAndExecute(...)` shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424155/javascript-how-to-get-setinterval-to-start-now/7424165#7424165 if this comes up more than just once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give the function a name, call it, and put the `setTimeout` in `$.getJSON`'s callback:

```
$(document).ready(getTicketData);

function getTicketData() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $.getJSON("data/ticket_data.json", function (result) {
        /*some more stuff here*/
        setTimeout(getTicketData, 30000);
    });
}
```

If you ever need to stop this timeout, have a look at [`clearTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp).