# How to restart interval after a short delay jquery

Tags: jquery, delay, setinterval, clearinterval

I am trying to repeat an interval on document ready. Interval repeats every 3 seconds but I want it halt it onmousemove event for 5 seconds and then restart interval.

This is my code as far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myInterval = setInterval(alertMe, 3000);

    function alertMe(){
        alert('jj');
    }

    $(document).mousemove(function(event){
        // I want delay 5 seconds and then initialize myInterval again
        setTimeout(function(){}, 5000);
        clearInterval(myInterval);
        setInterval(alertMe, 3000);
    });
});
```

Reference Answer 1: [JavaScript: How to get setInterval() to start now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424155/javascript-how-to-get-setinterval-to-start-now)

Reference Answer 2: [How to wait 5 seconds with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836105/how-to-wait-5-seconds-with-jquery)

Comment: mousemove or mousedown? Also the alert will block any timeout

Comment: i want actually delay start on mousemove and restart interval on mouse stop move

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly note that your question says you want to stop the interval on `mousedown`, yet your code uses `mousemove`.

Secondly, don't use `alert()` to test this as it blocks the UI from updating. Use `console.log()` instead.

Finally, to solve the issue, use a `setTimeout()` call in the mouse event to delay the restarting of the interval. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function logMe() {
    console.log('jj');
  }
  
  function startInterval() {
    return setInterval(logMe, 3000);
  }
  
  var interval = startInterval(), timeout;

  $(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      interval = startInterval();
    }, 2000); // note 2000 delay here, as it compounds with the 3000 delay on the 
              // interval to make a 5000ms delay
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why the `return setInterval(logMe, 3000);` ? To store the intervalID?

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code which is little modification to your code only.
You can use `mousedown` event handler and inside it clearinterval and set new interval after 5 seconds using settimeout

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myInterval = setInterval(alertMe, 3000);
    var myTimeout;

    function alertMe(){
        alert('jj');
    }

    $(document).mousedown(function(event){
        clearInterval(myInterval); // clear interval as soon as mouse over
        clearTimeout(myTimeout);
        // I want delay 5 seconds and then initialize myInterval again
        myTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
           myInterval = setInterval(alertMe, 3000); // set interval after 5 seconds
        }, 5000);
    });
});
```

Comment: You'll also need to clear the timeout, otherwise the interval will restart even if the mouse moves again before the delay finishes.